# PHP - Spoofing return-type covariance for code prediction

Tags: php, covariance, return-type, phpdoc

Consider:

```
abstract class BaseModel {
    protected static string $dataObjectClass;

    public function toDataObject(): ?IDataObject
    {
        return static::$dataObjectClass::from($this);
    }
}

class FooModel extends BaseModel {
    protected static string $dataObjectClass = FooDataObject::class;
}

$do = (new FooModel)->toDataObject();
```

Code prediction in IDEs like PHPStorm on `$do` would indicate a return type of `null|IDataObject` and... not tell me anything of value about its nature as an instance of `FooDataObject` except what *might* be defined in `IDataObject`.

Yet I can know with certainty as the programmer that the returned object will either be null or an instance of `FooDataObject`.

Are there any tricks to inform IDEs that the returned type can be a `FooDataObject`?

Two half-baked, hacky solutions I've tried are:

1. Override `toDataObject()` in the subclass and expand the return type to be `null|IDataObject|FooDataObject`. This works to unlock the properties and methods of `FooDataObject` for prediction but it means overloading a method for one sole, silly purpose -- ugly overhead.
2. Include `@method FooDataObject toDataObject()` in the subclass phpdoc. This is far leaner and cleaner but, of course, the `@method` notation seems to have zero support for multiple return types. Try to do `@method null|FooDataObject toDataObject()` and PHPStorm (at least) only recognizes the first type.

So any hints or tricks would be appreciated. I'm a stickler for code prediction and I want to establish a practice in this application that makes coding easier tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I test `@method` using the following I do indeed get auto completion from PhpStorm:

```
interface I{}
class Data implements I{}

abstract class P
{
    public function getThing(): ?I
    {
        return null;
    }
}


/**
 * @method Data getThing()
 */
class C extends P {}

(new C)->getThing();
```

[image]

As you mentioned, overriding the method only to change the return type does add redundancies, but you also get runtime type checking which may or may not be advantageous to you, especially because you can explicitly remove the null possibility from the return.

```php
interface I{}
class Data implements I{}

abstract class P
{
    public function getThing(): ?I
    {
        return null;
    }
}

class C extends P {
    public function getThing(): Data
    {
        return new Data;
    }
}

var_dump((new C)->getThing());
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/hdscV

**EDIT** Sorry, I forgot about the union type portion, but that is also working for me:

```php
interface I{}
class Data implements I{}

abstract class P
{
    public function getThing(): null|I
    {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * @method null|P getThing()
 */
class C extends P {
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, apparently I'm just insane because yep.. now it's working for me. I got no explanation why it didn't seem to be before. Thanks!